# Why is this code only changing one element and not both?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change 2 elements based on one input field, but jquery only changes text in one and not in both elements.

When I reverse order of elements in function. f.e.: #inCoin is first and then #receive_amount than it changes only #inCoin element

```html
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="How much do you want to {{$coin->add_type == 2 ? 'sell':'buy'}}" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" required>
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">{{$coin->currency->name}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly id="inCoin" placeholder="In {{$coin->gateway->name}}" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" required>
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">{{$coin->gateway->currency}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <p>You will receive this amount: <span id="receive_amount"></span> {{$coin->gateway->currency}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var min = "{{$coin->min_amount}}";
    var max = "{{$coin->max_amount}}";
    var price = "{{$price}}";
    var charge = "{{$general->trx_charge}}";

    $(document).on('change keyup', "#amount", function() {
        var val = $(this).val();

        if (parseFloat(val) >= parseFloat(min) && parseFloat(val) <= parseFloat(max)) {
            $("#amount").css("background-color", "#87E9B9");
            $("#submit").css("display", "block");
            $("#receive_amount").text((parseFloat(val) / price) * ((100 - charge) / 100)).toFixed(6);
            $("#inCoin").val((parseFloat(val) / price) * ((100 - charge) / 100)).toFixed(6);

        } else {
            $("#amount").css("background-color", "#F59898");
            $("#submit").css("display", "none");
            $("#receive_amount").text(' ');
            $("#inCoin").val(' ');
        }

    });
});
```

I expect that both #inCoin and #receive_amount will change based on #amount, but in reality it only changes the #receive_amount.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your console you will see an error like this.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text(...).toFixed is not a function
```

Move your toFixed(6) to inside the val() settings as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var min = "3";
  var max = "10";
  var price = "5";
  var charge = "3";

  $(document).on('change keyup', "#amount", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (parseFloat(val) >= parseFloat(min) && parseFloat(val) <= parseFloat(max)) {
      $("#amount").css("background-color", "#87E9B9");
      $("#submit").css("display", "block");
      $("#receive_amount").text((parseFloat(val) / price) * ((100 - charge) / 100).toFixed(6));
      $("#inCoin").val((parseFloat(val) / price) * ((100 - charge) / 100).toFixed(6));

    } else {
      $("#amount").css("background-color", "#F59898");
      $("#submit").css("display", "none");
      $("#receive_amount").text(' ');
      $("#inCoin").val(' ');
    }

  });
})
```

And this is breaking a rule of duplicate Ids.

```
<span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">{{$coin->gateway->currency}}</span>
```